# What does food in Soda-Dungeon 2 do?

Tags: soda-dungeon-2

When I equip my adventurers with frying pans they quite often produce food when hitting an enemy. But I seem to be unable to find any reference to it or any use for it?! Is it just a joke animation or is there something one can do with all this food?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Food can be used to upgrade the kitchen of the tavern alongside some coins. With each upgrade, you get a 5% boost to starting HP. Each level requires a different grouping of food to increase it one more level, as well as more coins.